# mysql.connector in python / cursor in for-loop only working for first row of table

Tags: python, mysql, for-loop, cursor, mysql-connector

I have a table and I want to translate columns 'topic' and 'review' of a row and store the entire table with their translations into a new table. It seems that the for-loop doesn't iterate over all rows of the input table. Only the first row is stored into the new table. Why?

```
database = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='root', host='localhost', database='test')

DBcursor = database.cursor(buffered=True)

query = ("SELECT * FROM test_de")

DBcursor.execute(query)


for (id, user_name, date, country, version, score, topic, review, url) in DBcursor:

    topic_trans = translate(topic, 'en')
    review_trans = translate(review, 'en')

    add_translation = ("INSERT INTO test_de_en(id, user_name, date, country, version, score, topic, review, url)"

                            "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

    translation_data = (id, user_name, date, country, version, score, topic_trans, review_trans, url)

    DBcursor.execute(add_translation, translation_data)

    database.commit()


DBcursor.close()

database.close()
```

Comment: Looks like the results in DBcursor get overwritten when you get to `DBcursor.execute(add_translation, translation_data)`. Perhaps try using a separate cursor to execute that part?

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You used the variable name "DBcursor" both inside and outside the for loop, so you're overwriting your variable and losing your resultSet.

If you use, for example, DBcursor1 outside and DBcursor2 inside, it should work.

Comment: Hello, this question is 7 ears old. I don't know what's the purpose of such a low quality answer to it without any code.